# Como obtener los valores de un array de inputs y pasarlos a un string?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola que tal espero que tengan un buen día.
Estoy haciendo un formulario donde agrego participantes y eventos.
Los participantes salen de una base de datos de la tabla usuarios.
Los eventos se van agregando dinámicamente con cajas de texto y un select donde aparecen los usuarios que se han asignado como participantes.
Realmente mi desafío esta a la hora de guardar los participantes en la tabla de eventos.
La tabla eventos tiene dos campos
participantes y Evento.
Se supone que en la columna de participantes se deben guardar los id de los participantes en forma de string para que a la hora de consultarlos se pueda usar un explode y asi mostrar la informacion.
Solo que no se como pasar el array que viene de los select a una cadena
los campos del formulario son estos:

```html
<td class="col-md-2 td-a">
  <input type="date" class="form-control evento" name="evento[]" autocomplete="off" />
</td>

<td class="col-md-4 td-a">
  <select class="form-control participante" name="participante[]" autocomplete="off" />
  </select>
</td>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Guardar</button>
```

Envio los datos por metodo $post

```
$evento = $_POST['evento'];
$participantes = $_POST['participante'];
```

Despues itero el array que me interesa que es el de participantes lo he hecho de las siguientes maneras.

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($participantes; $i++){
   echo $participantes[$i];
}
```

Y tambien he usado un foreach

```
foreach($pasticipantes as $participante){
    echo $participante;
}
```

Mi desafio esta al momento de utilizar las variables ya sea de participantes[$i] o $participante fuera de los iteradores obviamente solo me imprime el ultimo valor.

Y al utilizar metodos de array no me permite mi duda es como puedo usar los valores del array de participantes para poder guardarlos en la base de datos en un solo registro en la columna de participantes.
O si puedo crear un nuevo array con el formato de $array = array(valores) iterando el array de $participantes ya sea con for, while o foreach.
De antemano agradezco su tiempo y ojla espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver esto de antemano nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes juntar todos los valores del array `$_POST['participante']` en una cadena, separándolos por algún carácter especial, por ejemplo la coma `,`.

Para ello, utiliza la función `implode`:

```
$participantes = implode(',', $_POST['participante']); //De array a cadena
```

Así ya tendrías un valor de tipo cadena para guardarlo en el campo correspondiente de tu tabla.

Para darle la vuelta a ese valor (volver a convertirlo en array), simplemente tienes que usar la función `explode`, especificando el mismo carácter que usaste para separar:

```
$array = explode(',', $participantes); //De cadena a array
```

Esa solución viene genial cuando los valores son de tipo numérico, por ejemplo Ids., que posiblemente sea lo que estás enviando, no sé.

**Nota**.- El separador puede ser una cadena, no es obligatorio que sea un carácter sencillo.

Cuando no son de tipo numérico, puede interesar alguna de estas alternativas:

- Codificar el array en JSON, que también sería una cadena:

  ```
  $participantes = json_encode($_POST['participante']); //De array a cadena

  $array = json_decode($participantes, true); //De cadena a array
  ```
- Serializar el array al estilo de PHP:

  ```
  $participantes = serialize($_POST['participante']); //De array a cadena

  $array = unserialize($participantes); //De cadena a array
  ```

Entre estas dos alternativas, es preferible la de JSON, porque es un estándar que se puede manejar desde cualquier lenguaje, no te ata tanto a PHP.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvió de mucho y resolvió mi problema de antemano muchas gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo y compartir tus conocimientos.